# Visual studio not recognized asp tag when body tag is remove

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I have encountered a problem where visual studio does not recognized asp tag once the body tag is being removed. It shows unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'. How to make visual studio to recognize the asp tag when body tag is being removed?

ASP tag is being recognized:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox Text="123" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP tag is not being recognized:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox Text="123" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to make a page with invalid html?

Comment: @dman2306 FYI I am using the aspx file in mvc partial view due to requirement needed. Therefore, I would like to remove the duplicated html tag in aspx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use that page as a UserControl.

If that's the case you must change the directive from Page to Control and update the file type to `.ascx`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

would change to

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.ascx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: Would try this to see if it meet requirement